# Get last inserted item from Core Data, iOS

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ios, core-data

is there a way to get the last inserted item in a core data database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This returns the very last inserted object.

> setFetchLimit:1 and setFetchOffset:[number of all entries - 1]

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:**
I've extended @Olsi answer with sample code including the line to get number of all entities. Here's how I've done it:

```swift
    let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MyEntity")
    let allElementsCount = context.countForFetchRequest(request, error: nil)
    request.fetchLimit = 1
    request.fetchOffset = allElementsCount - 1
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
```

**Method 2:**
Howerver there's another approach using `sortDescriptors`. Not sure which is better fit, they both do the same job:

```swift
    let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MyEntity")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "momentTimeStamp", ascending: false)]
    request.fetchLimit = 1
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is supported natively by Core Data.  I guess your best bet is to add a "dateInserted" attribute to your entity.

Comment: I managed to do it through setFetchLimit: & setFetchOffset:, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: setFetchLimit:1 and setFetchOffset:[number of all entries - 1] - this returns the very last inserted object.