# How to get last inserted record from core database?

Tags: iphone, database, ipad, core-data

I am trying to fetch last inserted object from core database. But i did't find way to fetch last inserted object from database. Currently i am fetching all records from database in array and using last object of array for last inserted object.
But i want to fetch only single object from database.

Is there anyway to find a last single record from database.?

Thanks and regards
Sarabjit Singh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//=== Sort your record ======//
NSSortDescriptor *sorting = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sorting]];

NSArray *fetchObjects = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
NSMutableArray *lastIndex = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[lastIndex addObject:[fetchObjects objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Comment: Hey....but in this code you are fetching all records from database and after that you are getting last object from fetched array.......

Comment: // You can set fetch limit.
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];

Answer (score 0):

See this question: [Get last inserted item from Core Data, iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838424/get-last-inserted-item-from-core-data-ios)

The following is the key when running your fetch:

```
setFetchLimit:1 and setFetchOffset:[number of all entries - 1]
```

Comment: total number of objects in the data set